# Trimming a 2D array with a 1D array, Error: "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a mask for some number of electron trajectories, and in doing so, I need to cut some of the trajectory arrays to a certain length. All trajectories are stored in a 2D numpy array. I loop through all electrons to find the index to cut and store that value in: `outOfRangeIndex`. I then try to use this array to limit the 2D trajectory array using: `roundedRadiusTraj = roundedRadiusTraj[:, :outOfRangeIndex]`. This then gives the error: "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index".

Here is the full block of code for reference:

```
roundedRadiusTraj = np.round(posArray[:,3,:]/.002)
roundedRadiusTraj = roundedRadiusTraj.astype(int)
roundedZedTraj = np.round(posArray[:,2,:]/.002)
roundedZedTraj = roundedZedTraj.astype(int)

radiusOutOfRangeIndex = np.full(numElectrons, num_steps)
zedOutOfRangeIndex = np.full(numElectrons, num_steps)
outOfRangeIndex = np.zeros(numElectrons,int)
for traj in range(numElectrons):#iterates through each electron
    if (roundedRadiusTraj[traj,:] >= 2501).any():#if the radial position goes out of bounds
        radiusOutOfRangeIndex[traj]= np.min(np.where((roundedRadiusTraj[traj,:] >= 2501)))#find the first timestep this happens
    if ((roundedZedTraj[traj,:] < 0) | (roundedZedTraj[traj,:] >= 2001)).any():#if the Z position goes outof bounds
        zedOutOfRangeIndex[traj] = np.min(np.where((roundedZedTraj[traj,:] < 0) | (roundedZedTraj[traj,:] >= 2001)))   
    #NOW DECIDE WHICH DIMENSION GOES OUT OF BOUNDS FIRST
    outOfRangeIndex[traj] = np.minimum(radiusOutOfRangeIndex[traj],zedOutOfRangeIndex[traj])
    
roundedRadiusTraj = roundedRadiusTraj[:, :outOfRangeIndex]
```

Looking at other threads concerning this error, I've checked to make sure the arrays are numpy arrays and not lists, the index array is **int** and **1D**

It should be noted that with a single electron, a variation of what I'm trying does work properly: `roundedRadiusTraj = roundedRadiusTraj[:outOfRangeIndex]`.

I can also discreetly cut the arrays using something like this:

```
roundedRadiusTrajFirst = roundedRadiusTraj[0]
roundedRadiusTrajFirst = roundedRadiusTrajFirst[:outOfRangeIndex[0]]
```

but I'd rather not have to do this, as the number of electrons may vary.

I have also tried putting this array cutting into the loop using:
`roundedRadiusTraj[traj] = roundedRadiusTraj[traj, :outOfRangeIndex[traj]]`
but this gives me another error: "could not broadcast input array from shape (4450,) into shape (5500,)"